# how to make the mouse 'leave a trail' after hover?

Tags: jquery, colors, bind, mouseover, live

Hi to whoever is willing to help :)

I'm trying to code something I saw as an example on a website because even though they have provided the code I can't make it work.

Here is a link to where I got the example from:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/31/50-jquery-function-demos-for-aspiring-web-developers/

Scroll down to the "Bind() Unbind()" section. It's the second example with the orange and purple squares. I would like to know how to get that effect of having the color change, then remain changed and then change again if the mouse goes over the square a second time.

*i dont need the double click effect, just the color changing.

Thank you

Comment: So what have you tried? Did you click the "view code button"?

Comment: Yes I did but I got confused because it was just the jquery code (no css and html) + the code for the other effects in that example( double clicking and making more lines with squares).

Comment: It's always advisable to show an attempt and the problems you are having... even more-so when you already have the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base CSS for the div element is orange.

On mouseover it toggles a CSS class called `purplebg` which makes it purple when added, and reverts back to orange when mouseover fires again. That's pretty much it.

```
}).live('mouseover', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('purplebg');
});
```

Here is a simple [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SsDaG/1/)

Comment: Thank you, you're the best :) It's quite straight forward actually. I got confused with the rest of the code given for that example.